# Pass a value to a callback function

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I know that there are several questions, targeting this topic. But I haven't found a solution for my problem.

There is a webworker in my project which should manage all ajax calls. Because of this architecture I can't pass a callback function to the ajax function. My workaround was a token, which should be put into the worker's answer so the frontend can determine what to do.

So my call inside the worker looks like this:

```
ajax({
    success_func : function(data) {
        self.postMessage({
            task : cb,
            data : data
        }
    }
});
```

The most horrible thing I tested was

```
ajax({
    success_func : (function(cb) {
        return function(data) {
            self.postMessage({
                task : this.cb,
                data : data
            });
        }.bind({cb : cb});
    })(cb),
});
```

But as soon as I call the worker before the first ajax call was executed, I get two answers with different data but the same cb

How can I force the function to use the cb from the corresponding call and not the last one passed to the worker?

Comment: *webworker in my project which should manage all ajax calls.* why would you do this? This seems a very problematic design. This smells of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I thought it would be a good idea to let the worker handle some (synchronous) background tasks that would block the main script.

Comment: AJAX isn't synchronous though? The A means **asynchronous**, **A**synchronous **J**avaScript **A**nd **X**ML. It sounds like you want to just forget about the web worker

Comment: You cannot pass a function to a webworker.

Comment: @Liam I'm using XMLHttpRequest in synchronous mode in two requests.

Comment: @Bergi and that's the reason I tried the token. And the passing of the token to postMessage is the problem

Comment: Yeah don't do that, basically **never ever** send a synchronous http request. I'm guessing your struggling with the return type?

Comment: You need to read [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) this is your **actual problem**

Comment: @kuh-chan What token are you talking about? There's none in the code you posted

Comment: @Bergi the token is the "cb". And there's my problem.

Comment: @Liam I know how to return an answer from an asynchronous call. That's not the problem and it's working. Even if I dropped the sync requests, the problem I have won't be solved. The problem is the communication between worker and (let's say) main.js. If I have a call to the worker while an ajax call is still in progress, I get back the same token (cb) two times. And not both tokens as expected.

Comment: @kuh-chan `cb` is a function, not a token, right?